# Why won't badge notification work for Gmail on my S3?

Tags: notifications, gmail

I get badge notifications for all my other apps and email, but Gmail will not show the little red icon that shows the number of unread messages.  It used to work fine, but now it no longer does and it's driving me nuts.  I have all the notifications turned on (in the top menu bar and within the Gmail app itself).  Not sure what else I can do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that feature was removed around the time they added per-label/per-account notifications.

Answer (score 3):

The stock Gmail app on the Galaxy S3 does not have an unread count on the home screen icon.  However, you can use the stock email app to retrieve your Gmail and that app includes an unread count on the home screen.